# Is it possible to trigger an event on clicking the close button of jquery lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I am using the Jquery LightBox plugin. It works fine. I need an dialog box to be opened once i click the close button of the Jquery LightBox. But i couldn do so...Is that possible to track the close event of lightbox and trigger another event?

Please help

Comment: yes, find close botton code in js file

Comment: no.. i couldn.. if its a normal dialog box i can do that.. but not with lightbox.. If u have done that.. can u share me the code snippet please..

Comment: which lightbox plugin you are using?

Comment: search _finish() in this file, this function is called on close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source

```
$('#lightbox-loading-link,#lightbox-secNav-btnClose').click(function() {
    _finish();
    return false;
});
```

So just add an event handler to `#lightbox-secNav-btnClose` and it should work

```
$("body").on("click", "#lightbox-secNav-btnClose", function() {
    console.log("lightbox closed");
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.. But it worked only when i used as 
$("#lightbox-secNav-btnClose").click(function() { alert("clicked"); });

Comment: That's not a sustainable solution. What if user doesn't click to close icon or body and press just ESC key?

Comment: @sundowatch Or space, or the right mouse key, or "Hey Siri, ..." - Feel free to add another solution.

Comment: @sundowatch And that's why a reason for a DV?

Answer (score 2):

Replace _finish function in jquery-lightbox-0.5.js with below code:

```
function _finish() {
    $('#jquery-lightbox').remove();
    $('#jquery-overlay').fadeOut(function() { $('#jquery-overlay').remove(); });
    // Show some elements to avoid conflict with overlay in IE. These elements appear above the overlay.
    $('embed, object, select').css({ 'visibility' : 'visible' });

    var callback = settings.onClose;
    if($.isFunction(callback)) {
         callback.call();
    }
}
```

Add onClose in settings at top in jquery-lightbox-0.5.js file after activeImage;

```
// Don´t alter these variables in any way
imageArray: [],
activeImage: 0,         
onClose: null
```

Usage :

```
$('#gallery a').lightBox({ onClose : function() { alert('Hi'); }  } );
```

Comment: download working example of this here: http://vishalgyan.com/download_section/jQuery/jquery-lightbox-0.5-with-onClose.zip

Comment: If you put the same-way callback to _start function, it'll break all lightbox interface buttons (like lightbox-btn-close.gif). They are not showing (but still in html). Chrome devtools console say (for main Jquery): Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: The problem is solved by specifying in Lightbox call script urls to interface images with leading slash ($('my-gallery-sellector').lightBox({imageLoading : '/images/lightbox-ico-loading.gif'...).

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience I can recommend you to use [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)

There you have `onClosed` property on the init of the colorbox so it's easy as:

```
$("a.lightbox").colorbox({
    onClosed: function() {
        console.log('closed')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without modifying anything in lightbox.js:

```
<div onclick="close_lightbox()">Close Button</div>

function close_lightbox()
{
    lightbox.end();
}
```